# Find an isomorphism between $L(V,V)$ and the space of $n\times n$ matrices over $F$ with inner product $(A|B) = tr(AB^*)$

Tags: linear-algebra

This problem is rather difficult with me and I can't find a solution for the last point. Please help me:

> 1. Let $V$ be an $n$-dimensional inner product space over the field $F$ and let $L(V,V)$ be the space of linear operators on $V$. Show that ther is a unique inner product on $L(V,V)$ with the property that $||T_{\alpha, \beta} ||^{2}= ||\alpha||^{2} ||\beta||^{2}$ , here we suppose $T_{\alpha, \beta}(x) = (x|\beta)\alpha$.
> 2. Find an isomorphism between $L(V,V)$ with this inner product and the space of $n\times n$ matrices over $F$, with the inner product $(A|B) = tr(AB^*)$

I can solve the first point using basis for $L(V,V)$ includes $E_{p,\,q} (\alpha_{i}) = \delta_{ip}\alpha_{q}$ because we can prove that $E_{p,\,q} = T_{\alpha_{q}, \, \alpha_{p}}$, here we have ${(\alpha_{i})}_{i = 1}^{n}$ is basis of $V$. But I can't find any way to solve the second point.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand here: what is $\,\alpha,\,\beta\,$ in (1)? And in (2), what do we need that inner product for in order to find (or establish) an isomorphism between $\,L(V,V)\,$ and $\,M_n(F)\,$ ? This ismorphism exists without any reference to inner product or anything else but vector spaces (or, if one wants, as algebras, too)

Comment: I agree with DonAntonio. You want "isometric isomorphism" in the second question. Isomorphism is automatic by equality of dimension and does not refer to the inner product structure.

Comment: @julien: Oh, but the problem requires that you must specify a specific isomorphism, means a "non-singular preserving inner product linear transformation", not only point out that "there exists a isomorphism". Here isomorphism can be understood as a vector space isomorphism which also preserves inner product.

Comment: Ah, @leducquang! So this is precisely what I and Julien were talking about: you did **not** specify the isomorphism must be an isometry or an inner product preserving one... Anyway, choosing orthonormal bases can help, I presume.

Comment: @leducquang When dealing with vector spaces, isomorphism usually means vector space isomorphism. It there are inner-products and you want an inner-product preserving isomorphism, most people will say: isometric isomorphism (and not isomorphism).

Comment: Oh, so sorry for this. I get this problem from my book. Maybe in the context of this problem in the book, isomorphism can be understood in that way with no need to explain more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints: let $\{e_1,\ldots,e_n\}$ be an orthonormal basis of $V$.

1. Consider the inner product $(L_A|L_B) = \sum_{j=1}^n (L_Ae_j|L_Be_j)$. Verify that $\|T_{\alpha, \beta}\|^2 = \|\alpha\|^2 \|\beta\|^2$.
2. Consider the mapping that maps $L_A\in L(V,V)$ to $A\in M_n(F)$ by $L_A e_i = \sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij} e_j$ for each $i$, i.e. $A_{ij} = (L_A e_i|e_j)$. Verify that this is indeed an isomorphism and $(L_A|L_B)=(A|B)$.

Answer (score 2):

Note that
$$
\beta\longmapsto (\cdot,\beta)
$$
is an isometry between $V$ and the dual $V^*$.

Then observe that there is a natural isomorphism
$$
L(V,V)\simeq  V\otimes V
$$
where $\alpha\otimes \beta$ is identified with $T_{\alpha,\beta}$.

So the first question amounts to showing that there exists a unique inner-product on $V\otimes V$ such that $\| \alpha\otimes \beta \|=\| \alpha \| \| \beta\|$. This is true. And it is actually the standard way to put an inner product on the tensor product of two inner spaces. The defining formula is
$$
(\alpha\otimes \beta,\alpha'\otimes \beta')=(\alpha,\alpha')(\beta,\beta')
$$
from which we extend by linearity. By polarization, we clearly have uniqueness. So it only remains to check that the above actually defines an inner product on $V\otimes V$. The only delicate part is to verify that the claim: extend by linearity yields a well-defined operation.

For the second question, I think you meant isometric isomorphism, for otherwise this is true by dimension and regardless of the norms.

Now fix an orthonormal basis $(e_1,\ldots,e_n)$ of $V$, so that $L(V,V)$ is identified with $M_n(F)$ and so
$$
M_n(F)\simeq V\otimes V.
$$
Now for every $\alpha,\beta$, 
$$
T_{\alpha,\beta}^*(x)=\overline{(\alpha,x)}\beta=(x,\alpha)\beta
$$
so
$$
T_{\alpha,\beta}T_{\alpha,\beta}^*(x)=(x,\alpha)\|\beta\|^2\alpha.
$$
Now 
$$
\mbox{trace}T_{\alpha,\beta}T_{\alpha,\beta}^*=\sum_{i=1}^n(T_{\alpha,\beta}T_{\alpha,\beta}^*(e_i),e_i)=\|\beta\|^2\sum_{i=1}^n|(\alpha,e_i)|^2=\|\alpha\|^2\|\beta\|^2.
$$
Clearly, $(S,T)\longmapsto \mbox{trace}(ST^*)$ is an inner-product on $L(V,V)$ and the corresponding norm coincides with the previous one on elements $T_{\alpha,\beta}$, i.e. $\alpha\otimes \beta$.

The uniqueness of question 1 shows therefore that $L(V,V)\simeq V\otimes V$ is isometric to $M_n(F)$ equipped with $\mbox{trace}(ST^*)$.